# Windows phone emulator can't connect to UDP port error

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v, windows-phone-emulator

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10. The Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator used to work just fine, until I tried to shut Hyper-V down (unsuccessfully).

[image: Hyper-V]

When rebooting, Windows displayed that there is a problem and that it won't be able to complete the task and that it will revert to its original state.

When it started again Hyper-V was still activated, but a problem started showing up when I started the emulator from Visual Studio.

[image: Emulator View]

And after a few minutes it prompts this error:

[image: UDP Port]

I know that the virtual machine is running because I can access it from the Hyper-V Manager:

[image: Hyper-V Manager]

---

I tried all solutions available online:

1. Deleting the virtual machine, and restarting Visual Studio as administrator.
2. Deleting the internal Switch and re-creating it (manually and by running the emulator from Visual Studio)
   [image: Switch]
3. Shutting down the FireWall.
4. Sharing the WIFI internet access to the virtual network.

Nothing worked. Anyone has seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how, but after a number of reboots the emulator works again.
This is maybe some weird bug with Hyper-V that was fixed silently.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and tried many solutions and got the emulator working by doing the below steps:

1. Remove all the virtual switches from "Virtual Switch manager"
2. Restart your system.
3. Goto Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing
   Center -> Advanced sharing settings
4. And enable "Turn on Network discovery" and "Turn on file and printer
   sharing" for all network profiles. [Sharing screen for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsBuB.png)
5. Start emulator.

Done.